# extract equal number of frames for all videos

Tags: python, opencv3.0

I am working on action recognition. I'm using `opencv` and `python`.

I want to extract equal number of frames (say `n` frames) from each video. My videos are of different lengths and I want to skip some frames in which the duration of the video is longer.

Can anyone give me an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you use imshow to display the frames of a video, you do so within a for/while loop, which is usually infinite. Setting the for/while loop to run `n` times will give you the first n frames of the video. In python, you can use imwrite with filename that changes with every iteration

```
filename = 'frame' + str(i)
imwrite(filename, img)
```